# Logging out of Exchange ActiveSync

Tags: exchange-server, activesync

Microsoft's documentation is quite detailed about how to create a relationship between a client & server, but I haven't been able to find any details as to how to terminate the relationship?

As the server has quite broad rights on the client, I suspect it's a purely server-side thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "logging out" of an ActiveSync session, at least from the protocol's perspective. Each call is stateless, so as long as the client device retains the account credentials it can issue another synchronization command at any time.

If you're asking about Exchange administrative configuration relating to ActiveSync, you should try [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) instead.

Comment: Yes, that's what I basically figured as well. But the server still has to keep quite a lot of state around (`SyncKey`, `PolicyID`, `IMEI`-numbers, etc.), and it would be nice to known when it can safely throw that away.

Comment: The server could throw it away at any time and force the client to do a full resync.